# Modificar o src de várias imagens individualmente

Tags: javascript

Eu preciso de um *script* que modifique o atributo `src` de várias imagens.

A ideia é substituir alguns trechos da URL apenas, mas o problema é que vão ser várias imagens com a mesma classe.

Vai ser um gerador de tbumbnail. A imagem original vai vir com uma dimensão e eu quero mudar através da URL, por exemplo:

```
redir.com?url=imgs.com/img3356/100x150/img.jpg
```

para

```
imgs.com/img3356/300x500/img.jpg
```

O *script* deve rodar antes da página carregar, porque o endereço original vai ser uma página que faz a mesma função usando PHP, mas eu só quero que ela rode se o *script* não funcionar.

**O que já tentei:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img.miniatura").each(function() {
        var url_img = $(this).attr("src");
        var nova_url = url_img.replace("s72-c", "s150-c100");
        $(this).attr("src", nova_url);
        document.write(nova_url);
    });
});
```

É algo assim que eu estava precisando, só que, no caso, cada URL é bem diferente. A única coisa em comum é a parte das dimensões da imagem. e eu preciso trocar mais de um trecho. Eu fiz um teste com esse *script* ai mas, como eu falei, ainda não funciona exatamente como eu preciso. Não entendo muito bem do que você fez na variável *regex* ai, mas, pelo que pude notar, depende de a URL mudar só aquele trecho, o que não é o caso.

Comment: Tenho a impressão que mesmo que alguma resposta dê certo, o caminho escolhido para resolver o problema seja longe do ideal. Claro que sem mais detalhes, é só um palpite.

Comment: E qual caminho você me indicaria ?

Comment: Como não sei os detalhes, é meio complicado. O que você quer dizer com "se o script não funcionar"? Se é pra galeria de fotos ou lightbox, melhor seria já gerar com os URLs das miniaturas, e linkar para as grandes, não? (considerando que você usa PHP)

Comment: Vou explicar melhor: a página vai ter  várias imagens com tamanhos definido. Mas eu quero mudar esses tamanhos. Mudando a url, muda o tamanho da imagem. Ai eu fiz um esquema em php para fazer isso para mim. então a url da imagem vem como um parametro do endereço da página php que eu usei para fazer isso. Mas eu não quero usar o php sem necessidade, então quero um script que faça isso. Mas caso o javascript esteja desabilitado no navegador, é bom ter a solução em php. Eu não para gerar já com as urls das miniaturas porque eu estou usando a plataforma blogger, não aceita php.

Comment: É relativamente simples trocar as URLS por JS, mas vai ser sempre um remendo. Mas se é a única solução possível, vamos aguardar alguma resposta então.

Comment: Vi que o que a única coisa que se mantém estático na URL das imagens do blogger são o nome delas. Então você poderia criar uma padrão no nome delas, por exemplo: "100x150_nomeimg.png". Isso seria viável?

Comment: Até daria, mas ia depender de uma ação manual. Não tem como pegar só pela classe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se tudo o que precisas fazer é trocar `100x150` por `300x500`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img.miniatura").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("/100x150/", "/300x500/"));
    });
});
```

## Exemplo

Para efeitos de demonstração, vamos usar linhas de texto ao invés do atributo `src`, trocando assim o HTML para vermos a diferença entre o código fonte e o que é apresentado na página:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // simulação em texto para vermos fácilmente
  $("p.miniatura").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace("/100x150/", "/300x500/"));
  });

  // troca como pretendido na SRC
  $("img.miniatura").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("/100x150/", "/300x500/"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="miniatura">redir.com?url=imgs.com/img3356/100x150/img1.jpg</p>
<p class="miniatura">redir.com?url=imgs.com/img3356/100x150/img2.jpg</p>
<p class="miniatura">redir.com?url=imgs.com/img3356/100x150/img3.jpg</p>
<p class="miniatura">redir.com?url=imgs.com/img3356/100x150/img4.jpg</p>

<img class="miniatura" src="redir.com?url=imgs.com/img3356/100x150/img1.jpg" />
<img class="miniatura" src="redir.com?url=imgs.com/img3356/100x150/img2.jpg" />
<img class="miniatura" src="redir.com?url=imgs.com/img3356/100x150/img3.jpg" />
<img class="miniatura" src="redir.com?url=imgs.com/img3356/100x150/img4.jpg" />
```

Comment: Obrigado ! Eu queria trocar dois trechos, mas ai é só adaptar. A solução do Rafael Almeida também é boa, mas é um pouco complicada. Upvote para as duas.

Answer (score 3):

Se entendi bem, você quer substituir o caminho atual da imagem por um novo caminho, sendo que tal caminho especifica um tamanho diferente? Fiz de uma maneira aqui para substituir o caminho, você pode tentar adaptar para chegar a conclusão.

Note que eu estou utilizando uma URL diferente da que você especificou, mas a solução pode ser adaptada como eu já disse, irei lhe mostrar como. Minha imagem é essa:

```
<img src="http://www.rafaelalmeida.net78.net/exemplos/sopt/56952-src-img/100x150.png" class="thumb"/>
```

Perceba que é no nome da imagem que o tamanho é especificado, sendo "300x340.png" a imagem com outro tamanho. Pois bem, vamos lá.

### Código

Primeiro precisamos percorrer todos os elementos que tenham a classe "thumb", após isso, pegar o seu valor atual que está no atributo "src", logo:

```
$("img.thumb").each(function() {
    // Pega o caminho atual
    var img_path = $(this).attr("src");
});
```

Achei adequado usar `regex` para resolver o problema, então fiz um que pega o tamanho da imagem:

```
var regex = /rafaelalmeida.net78.net\/exemplos\/sopt\/56952-src-img\/(.+).png/;
```

Perceba que o que está está entre os parênteses é o valor a ser pego, logo, no seu caso ficaria assim:

```
var regex = /redir.com\?url=imgs.com\/img3356\/(.+)\/img.jpg/;
```

Com o regex em mãos, testamos se a imagem realmente atende aos requisitos, se sim, pegamos o valor que o regex nos retorna e verificamos se é o valor que quer trocar (no seu caso "100x1500":

```
if (regex.test(img_path)) {
    // Se o caminho da imagem bater com o regex...
    // Especifica o tamanho atual
    var size = img_path.match(regex)[1];
    if (size == "100x150") {
        // Se o tamanho for 100x150...
    }
}
```

Agora é simples, substituímos a string que tinha o antigo valor para o novo utilizando o mesmo regex e finalmente mudamos o valor de `src` para o novo caminho:

```
// Substitui o antigo caminho com o novo tamanho
var new_path = img_path.replace(size, "300x340");
// Atribui o novo valor ao atributo "src"
$(this).attr("src", new_path);
```

---

### Código final

Com isso temos nosso código final:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Percore todas as imagens com a classe "thumb"
    $("img.thumb").each(function() {
        // Pega o caminho atual
        var img_path = $(this).attr("src");
        // Define o regex
        var regex = /rafaelalmeida.net78.net\/exemplos\/sopt\/56952-src-img\/(.+).png/;
        if (regex.test(img_path)) {
            // Se o caminho da imagem bater com o regex...
            // Especifica o tamanho atual
            var size = img_path.match(regex)[1];
            if (size == "100x150") {
                // Se o tamanho for 100x150...
                // Substitui o antigo caminho com o novo tamanho
                var new_path = img_path.replace(size, "300x340");
                // Atribui o novo valor ao atributo "src"
                $(this).attr("src", new_path);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cmt60bqe/

Eu usei dois endereços diferentes para as imagens, um com o www e outro sem, para ver que o regex funciona com ambos.